# Can you remove the `translatable` option to a matrix field without losing locale content?

Tags: matrix, localization

One of our admins have mistakenly added the `translatable` option to an important matrix field. We were using this option to synchronise content blocks across multiple languages.

This is the our main “Block Matrix Field” which is used across *many* of our templates and we have more than 5 different languages.

If I try to remove the `translatable` flag to the block matrix, it overwrites all the content for the matrix for all the languages on the first save.

We need to revert this change somehow, but we’re unsure of when the error was introduced.

Is it possible to make sure that the flag is disabled *without losing all our content*? I have a DB backup of before we did any saves with the flag disabled, which means that we can follow a recipe if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer but one possible path if an easier option doesn't surface.

**Sprout Import** supports importing content into a Matrix field and multiple imports can be created to handle multiple locales while still matching things back to the parent entry.

- Example of [importing content to a Matrix field](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import/docs/special-data-types/importing-matrix-data)
- Example of [importing content for multiple locales](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import/docs/special-data-types/importing-multiple-languages)
- Example of how to [generate a JSON Import file in your Craft templates](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/import/docs/seed-data/faker-and-fake-data). While this example uses fake data, you could update the loop to output the content you need to re-import.

It's likely you'll have a handful of relationships in your content that you'll need to make sure resolve correctly as well if you re-import your content, so depending on how your content is set up there may be a few more tricky parts to work through. But this is one possible path if other options seem like the may require a lot of manual steps.

Be sure to test this in a development environment and make the appropriate backups before modifying any live content.